# How to I move the current file to a folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to move the current file to a folder and remove it from the one that it is in, based on a cell value change.  Here is what I have:

```
 function onEdit() {

var File = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var TransferComplete = File.getSheetByName("Sheet9").getRange("E24").getValue();

var ActiveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("a0lweiurnawoeiuranwv");
var ArchiveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("apsleriuoavwnoeiura");  



  if (TransferComplete = "Yes" ) 
  {ArchiveFolder.addFile(File) && ActiveFolder.removeFile(File)};


}
```

The error says that it cant find "add file" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move a file, you must first get the file itself as a file and not as a spreadsheet.

You need to use `DriveApp.getFileById()` to retrieve a file object that you can then pass into `ArchiveFolder.addFile()`.

Additionally you have some syntax errors with your code.

- You are using an assignment operator `=` instead of a comparative operator `==` or `'==='` to compare `TransferComplete` to `"Yes"`
- You don't need a statement seperator `;` at the end of an if statement
- You are using `&&` to separate two statements, you need to separate them like so

  `if(TransferComplete == "Yes" ){
        ArchiveFolder.addFile(File);
        ActiveFolder.removeFile(File);
    }`

Corrected code:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId());
  var transfeComplete = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet9").getRange("E24").getValue();

  var activeFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("a0lweiurnawoeiuranwv");
  var archivefolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("apsleriuoavwnoeiura");  

  if (transfeComplete === "Yes" ){
    archivefolder.addFile(file);
    activeFolder.removeFile(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  But what I need to do is get the current file... not file by ID... is there a way to do this?

Comment: Disregard... I see how you managed that.  Thank you!  Will test and mark as answered!

Comment: @user2048913 Perfect, it worked for me during my tests. It should definitely work for you.

Comment: Thanks!  Marked as answered!