# Set Drive Folder Location for Dynamically Created Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an app I've been building that sends a Google Form out based on responses from another google form, and and events on a calendar.

The problem I'm having is so simple and frustrating: the forms that are created are dropped right into my main "My Drive".

I really need to have all these forms stored somewhere other than my main drive, and I cannot find anything anywhere.

**Again:**
*I've come across a couple examples of copying and deleting files (you can't actually move) to get into a different folder. Have been unable to get this to work, and also doubt if this would work because it is linked to the response form.*

Have no code examples, because I haven't found anything close. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I move the current file to a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850598/how-to-i-move-the-current-file-to-a-folder)

Comment: It's not possible to set a drive folder location for newly created files. Instead you should move to the destination folder, that is why I'm flagged this question as a possible duplicate of the referred question.

Comment: @Rubén I don't think this is a duplicate.
As I already mention in italics, I have seen some articles suggest copying to desired folder, and deleting original.
However, this creates a new file, with a new ID, which I believe will break my destination for responses.

Comment: I still think that is a duplicate as the accepted answer to the referred question describe the core of the solution: first you should get the file object, then add it to the destination folder, then remove it from the original folder.

Comment: @Rubén thanks i'll get to work on it here and see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125464/discussion-between-ruben-and-tmkiefer).

Answer (score 5):

**Answer: adding the file object to destination folder, and removing the original works. It allows the destination spreadsheet attached to the form to still receive responses.**

Here is the code that I used to accomplish this:

```
function moveForm() {
  var myDId = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getId();

  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(myDId);
  var archiveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B2GEcLNd0NO4ZEMtbGZBdmZibzA");

  var newForms = rootFolder.getFilesByName('Let\'s meet!');
  while (newForms.hasNext()) {
    var newForm = newForms.next();
    archiveFolder.addFile(newForm)
    rootFolder.removeFile(newForm);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have done a similar function to this